# Custom Class inside Extended application class not getting recognized?

Tags: android, class, extends

I need to create a global Arraylist consisting Instances of my custom class 'Book' to be used across the application.

So I created a file 'MyBooks.java' containing 'MyBooks' class (extending application class) in which custom class 'Book' and Arraylist 'Booklist' are defined.

In the Main Activity file 'ExampledroidActivity.java' I need to load data from server, create 'Book' instances and add these instances to the ArrayList 'BookList'.

the problem is that it **doesn't seem to recognize Book class** in file 'ExampledroidActivity.java'.

Can Someone plz look at the code and point out what i am doing wrong.

Code from both files is given below

MyBooks.java -

```
package com.dubloo.exampledroid;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Application;

public class MyBooks extends Application {

    public class Book {

        public int No;
        public String Name;
        public String Author;
        public boolean IsAvailable;

     //  constructor
        public Book(int bookNo, String bookName, String bookAuthor, boolean bookIsAvailable) {
                    No = bookNo;
                    Name = bookName;
                    Author = bookAuthor;
                    IsAvailable = bookIsAvailable;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Book> BookList  = new ArrayList<Book>();

}
```

ExampledroidActivity.java -

```
package com.dubloo.exampledroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class ExampledroidActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MyBooks someBooks = ((MyBooks)getApplicationContext());

//here I get data from a server 
//for this example generating dummy data

        for(int n=1; n<20; n++){
            String Name = "The Book" + n;
            String Author = "Blah " + n;
            boolean IsAvailable = true;

//declare here an instance of class Book - in this part book class is not recognized
//definately doing some thing wrong here

            someBooks.Book thisBook = new someBooks.Book(n, Name, Author, IsAvailable);

//add book to the Booklist Arraylist

            someBooks.BookList.add(thisBook);
        }        


}

}
```

If its a noob question plz bear with me,
Thanks in advance,

Shobhit

Comment: what do you mean by recognize? Whats the error?

Comment: Can we see the stack trace or the error's message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better answer could be to

- separate you class book in another file (Book.java)
- make the BookList private and provide accessors (setter / getter )
- respect java naming conventions  : class start by upperCase letter then camel case, variables start with lowerCase letter then camel case.
- make your android application class a singleton.

There are some flaws in your design so far, but go on learning, Android is fun.

Regards, 
   Stéphane

Comment: thanks as you can see i am new both to java and android... i see now separating the book class is clearly the better way

Answer (score 1):

Your inner class could be static.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: thanks, it was really this easy... i wasted 2 hrs of my life i'll never get back, in second file i had to import com.dubloo.menudroid.MyBooks.Book;

Comment: few mins to go before stackoverflow lets me